# Disable force in forcelayout algorithm in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using force layout algorithm to draw a graph. But I want the user to be able to disable the force layout algorithm and be able to move the nodes around. I am following the example [here](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/)  (P is for pinning) to use as a base to build my code.

However, I want the user to appreciate the beauty of force based algorithms and hence want dragging and pinning to be enabled only after user presses the button "Make draggable".

Here is the code I am using...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>

    .node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .link {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: .6;
    }


</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spatial Social Network</title>

    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The network</h1>

    <script>
        var width = 500,
            height = 500;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();


        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

         var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-120)
                .linkDistance(30)
                .size([width, height]);

        /*Drag and pin*/
        var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("dragstart", dragstart)
            .on("drag", dragmove)
            .on("dragend", dragend);
        function dragstart(d, i) {
            alert("I am here");
            force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
        }
        function dragmove(d, i) {
            d.px += d3.event.dx;
            d.py += d3.event.dy;
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
        }
        function dragend(d, i) {
            d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
            force.resume();
        }
        function releasenode(d) {
            d.fixed = false; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
            //force.resume();
        }
        /*Drag and pin*/

        svg.append('text')
            .attr("x", 2)
            .attr("y", 20)
            .text("Force Layout")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("fill", "red");


        d3.json("jsonGraph.json", function(error, graph) {
            if (error) throw error;


            //console.log(graph.nodes);

            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link");


            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); })
                .call(force.drag);                

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

            force.on("tick", function() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            });



        });

        function MakeDraggable()
        {
            alert("here");
            d3.json("jsonGraph.json", function(error, graph) {
                if (error) throw error;


                force
                    .nodes(null)
                    .links(null)
                    .start();

                var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                    .data(graph.links)
                    .enter().append("line")
                    .attr("class", "link");

                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(graph.nodes)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); })
                    //.call(force.drag);
                    .call(node_drag)
                    .on('dblclick', releasenode);

                //force.stop();

            });
        }



    </script>

     <input type="button" name="MakeDraggable" value="Make Draggable!" onClick="MakeDraggable()"></input> 

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any change in behavior even after pressing the button "Make Draggable!".

Here is the json file I am using to read the graph:

```
{
"directed": false,
"graph": {
    "name": "Fun Graph"
},
"nodes": [
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "A"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "C"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "B"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "E"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "D"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "G"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "F"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "I"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "H"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "K"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "J"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "id": "M"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "L"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "O"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "id": "N"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 8
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 9
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 4
    },
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 7
    },
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 12
    },
    {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 4
    },
    {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 5
    },
    {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 6
    },
    {
        "source": 4,
        "target": 7
    },
    {
        "source": 4,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 4,
        "target": 12
    },
    {
        "source": 5,
        "target": 7
    },
    {
        "source": 5,
        "target": 8
    },
    {
        "source": 6,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 6,
        "target": 12
    },
    {
        "source": 7,
        "target": 13
    },
    {
        "source": 7,
        "target": 8
    },
    {
        "source": 9,
        "target": 14
    },
    {
        "source": 10,
        "target": 11
    },
    {
        "source": 10,
        "target": 14
    },
    {
        "source": 12,
        "target": 13
    }
],
"multigraph": false
}
```

I am new to D3 and not sure where I am going wrong.

```
  [1]: http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On button click you don't need to recreate/reload the full force layout:

```
function MakeDraggable()
        {
            alert("here");
            d3.json("jsonGraph.json", function(error, graph) {
                if (error) throw error;


                force
                    .nodes(null)
                    .links(null)
                    .start();
```

This can be done simply by:

```
function MakeDraggable() {
  svg.selectAll(".node").call(node_drag);//attach the drag behavior
}
```

working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1wl3eNkwaZs3BHRmLQs?p=preview)

Hope this helps!